# Wireframe node has no effect on bumpmap

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

Im trying to use a wireframe node to influence the height of a bump node, but it dosn't seem to have any effect:
[image: Wireframe Bump]

As you can see in the second image, the wireframe node is behaving properly because it influences the diffuse colour perfectly:
[image: Wireframe Diffuse]

Any solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be an issue with that node in conjunction with the *Bump* node. One solution that appears to work is using the *Wireframe* node in conjunction with a *Normal Map* node:

[image]

These nodes render a result like this:

[image]

Notice that these values can be inverted as well:

[image]

**One word of warning** thanks to @WChagrin:

> I would say that that's almost certainly undefined behavior. The colored pixels in the normal map are supposed to represent unit vectors in tangent space. When the wireframe node outputs a value of 0, that's coerced into the vector <0, 0, 0>, which is not only non-unit, but non-normalizable. That is, trying to normalize it would require division by zero. Relying on this behavior is probably a Bad Idea™.

Comment: ...That *shouldn't* work

Comment: Seems to though . . . you can also influence the *Strength* value with similar results.

Comment: So do you think this is a bug?

Comment: I didn't know you got yellow on a normal map, this is the strangest thing ever.

Comment: It would appear so, the *Wireframe* node doesn't appear to output a value usable by the *Bump* node.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms You in Cycles?

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise No, I'm still right, the bump nodes dosen't support this strange yellow normal map that you've created. It also won't work with a brick texture

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise I'm not that crazy! :P

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Meaning you are using Cycles?

Comment: I think we should [take this discussion to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20606/discussion-between-noviceindisguise-and-giantcowfilms).

Comment: It does appear to be bug because I have baked the output from the wireframe node and it works perfectly. I can't recreate your yellow normal map (???), but I can confirm that the brick texture works fine, when the wireframe dosn't. I will go and log this on the bug tracker, Thanks for all your help guys.

Comment: @ChristyJames So you copied my nodes exactly and it didn't work?

Comment: @ChristyJames I don't think it is a bug, if it isn't mind telling us what they have said

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Yep, your node setup worked just as in your pictures, but im trying to apply it to a complex mesh and the "Object Space" dosnt really give the right kind of results.

Comment: @ChristyJames Did you come up with a better result or do you want me to whip one up?

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise I made a workaround by baking the output of the wireframe node to an image file, and then using that image file to influence the height of the bump node, and that works fine for me. It would be interesting to find out why the wireframe node dosnt talk to the bump node though.... :)

Comment: @ChristyJames You can add your workaround as an answer. Glad you found something that worked! I wondered if baking a texture might do the trick. Glad it is solved!

Comment: I would say that that's almost certainly undefined behavior. The colored pixels in the normal map are supposed to represent unit vectors in tangent space. When the wireframe node outputs a value of `0`, that's coerced into the vector `<0, 0, 0>`, which is not only non-unit, but non-normalizable. That is, trying to normalize it would require division by zero. Relying on this behavior is probably a Bad Idea™.

Comment: @WChargin Excellent explanation! Mind if I add that to the answer?

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise please do.

Comment: @WChargin I knew something was up A+ for spotting it :D

Answer (score 2):

This problem appears to be caused by the Wireframe node not talking to the Bump node properly. After a bit of disscussion and help from others in the comments I developed this workaround by baking the wireframe output to a file and using the file to influence the Bump node:

[image]

Comment: Go ahead and accept your answer, it helps site stats

Answer (score 1):

Why you can't see anything:

The reason (or at least one of) is due to a [limitation of normal mapping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21035/how-can-a-normal-map-affect-the-look-of-a-model/21037#21037). All that normal mapping can do is trick cycles into think the face is at a different ***angle***. In your case, if you look at what you're trying to create from the top, all the faces are the same angle. In order for this to work, you need a bit of a slope.

Using displacement would work well, except in order to have enough geometry to displace, you will mess up the wire frame :/

The reason why the normal map node works, is that it supports some very unconventional normal maps. The bump map node is more particular about its output.

As far as  Ray Mairlot's comment, a brick texture won't work form the bump map node either, I have tested it to check, there is only a slight edge visible along the slope that occurs between the bricks.

**The bump and normal nodes are different:**

The Normal Map node takes a color representation of a normal vector and turns it into a vector.

The bump nodes samples 2 areas on the height map and compares the angle the find the vector. since there is only black and white, it will only find 90 degree angles and therefore not show any edge.

*Paraphrased [From the wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/More)*

Comment: Doesn't work on a sphere, I have a solution (I think)

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Yes, it wouldn't, still no angle. the *height map being converted* needs to have a gradient in order to have an angle to give the illusion of height.

Comment: Then why can a black and white brick texture create a bump effect?

Comment: I tried mixing RGB values with the Wireframe node, and then putting that into the *Bump* node, and that didn't work either.

Comment: I think the bump node is a bit fussier....

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Any ideas why?

Comment: @GiantCowFilms I have tried using the brick texture using the node setup in the question and it *does* work. I have also never had an issue of using only black and white bump maps without a 'slope'.

Comment: @RayMairlot I protest... did you use *only* **Black** and **White** bricks?

Comment: @GiantCowFilms http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=82889 Pure black and white.

Comment: @RayMairlot Precisely my point! that is not correct... there is a single line of at a 90 degree angle, with no height specification whats so ever! That is exactly what I said would happen.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/TBbHX.png Look at this normal map. It is not at all going to produce accurate results!

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Then I honestly have no idea what you are talking about and nor any idea why a brick texture would work and a wireframe wouldn't.

Comment: The wire-frame did the same thing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20608/discussion-between-giantcowfilms-and-ray-mairlot).