# Seams visible after baking normal map

Tags: uv, blender-internal-render-engine, normals, baking

[image]

Can anyone give a solution how to bake normal map properly?

On this picture cubes are shown located next to each other, but they are in the same position when I bake them.

The main problem is with hard edges. I tried to use UVs in T shape, tried to place islands together and separately but the problem persists.

I tried several diferent methods in Blender and Substance Desiger but I realy don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help.
If it's possible please post step by step instructions.

Thanks

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41184/baked-normal-map-from-high-poly-bad-corners ? It could be that low-poly has too low polycount. Also from the normal map it seems that low-poly doesn't have normals split that can cause shading artifacts.

Comment: any precise instuctions?!

Comment: Your low-poly object has shading mode set to smooth, but it seems to have [bad shading](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges) because of absence of Edge Split modifier or Autosmooth option. Also make low-poly to be wrapped around high-poly, so their surfaces should be close. You might want to look at [baking normal maps in BI](http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/bake-normal-maps.php)