# Normal map fragmented aspect

Tags: normals, texture-baking, baking, normal-map, polycount

I have this creepy issue with normal baking.
As you see, the result gives me a fragmented skin aspect. The fragments are the faces of the LOWPOLY.

Anyone knows why? Doubled the normal map resolution, changes nothing.***

Thank you !!

[image: Creepy fragmented skin]

Comment: Set the shading of the lowpoly to smooth.. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41184/baked-normal-map-from-high-poly-bad-corners

Comment: Oh genius!!! Works perfectly. Thank you
Somewhat feels like it should be automatic