# Unusual lines coming up in normal map!

Tags: modeling

I'm pretty much new to Blender. Currently, I have been following Andrew Price's Anvil series and I have come across this problem of lines popping up in my normal. It is kind of frustrating since it is showing up in the render as well. Could use some help here! Thanks

[image]

Comment: Could you point out which are the unusual line?

Comment: Did you enable smooth shading for the lowpoly?

Comment: @MrZak No. Should I?

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42048/1245

Comment: @MrZak Thanks a lot! The smooth shading helped. Also for the high poly I used the smooth brush kind because the problem seemed to arise from there. Sorry for the trouble