# My normal map isn't working

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, mesh, normals, baking

I've been having troubles with baking some high-rez meshes and it seems that the problem is not my baking, but something else. I've added some topology to a "brick", retopo-ed it and then baked it, then I've tried applying it in the node editor and.. well.. nothing happened.
Here's the high-rez mesh:
[image]
Low-rez:
[image] 
Render:
[image]

Comment: First of all set both meshes to smooth shading before baking. Secondly is that correct that you added material with normal map on the highpoly object? The whole idea behind normal map is using it on lowpoly object

Comment: @MrZak First: how does that help the baking process? I thought smooth shading didn't add anything to the topology/quality of the actual mesh. I thought it was purely for better looks in the viewport/render mode. Second: no, I'm 100% sure it's on the low poly mesh. The name of the low poly one is "untitled" as you can see upper right.

Comment: *"it was purely for better looks in the viewport/render mode"* no it isn't. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42048/1245 for detailed answer. Tldr is you always want it to be on when baking normal maps unless you want faceted lines from each face to be coming through on normal map. I don't get what isn't as expected in the normal map result as "untitled" and "cube" meshes look similar; it depends on the goal but the lowpoly looks too highpoly though so maybe that's why you don't see difference betwene highpoly and lowpoly

Comment: @MrZak High-poly one has around 200k verts, while the other one has around 30k. I rendered both and could clearly see the difference... I'm really confused since it doesn't make any sense to me. I mean, even if the normal map weren't baked correctly, it still isn't applying it to the mesh at all (through the node editor).