# How to quickly create a cable easily editable?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

How can i quickly create a cable that i can edit easily to position it, deform it and add gravity?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64887/cable-bump-how-would-you-do-it/64901

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a curve, add one by doing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> then *Curve* > *Bezier*. Place and orient the controll points of your cable, to deform it and add gravity select both points and press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Subdivide*. From <kbd>V</kbd> menu set the intermediate cuts to *Automatic* to keep a smooth curve, then position it. If you add multiple cuts spread them to get some space to keep a smooth line.

To make that curve have some volume set the *Fill* mode to *Full*. In the *Geometry* rollout under the "Bevel" adjust the *Depth* for the width of the cable and the resolution for the amount of sides.

[image]

Comment: Also adding some details is possible by using Bevel object which should be another curve and which can have desired form of the cable.

Comment: Yes and also this allows to edit the radius of the cables of all at once.