# How exactly does the Strength input of Blender's bump nodes work?

Tags: normals

From the Blender Docs:

> Strength

```
Strength of the bump mapping effect, interpolating between no bump mapping and full bump mapping
```

The idea of mixing together two effects isn't new to me, it makes sense, when I say, mix a blue diffuse shader with a red diffuse shader and plug it into the Material Output, the color would be a 50% mix of red and 50% of blue, getting me a new color. I can use the Fac input to precisely control the mixing to my liking

From what I know about bump maps, we calculate the derivatives of a specific pixel on a bump map when it's mapped to a mesh to find exactly where the new, perturbed normal on a part of the mesh should point

What does it mean to interpolate/mix between no and full bump mapping logically, however? In mixing between two diffuse colors, we mix the colors. But what exactly is mixed when we interpolate/mix between full and no bump mapping?

If a specific pixel on the bump-map perturbs the normal say to the right at 100% strength, at 50% strength would it only say, perturb it half as much to the right?

How does it work with the Distance input? If the distance = 1, would 50% strength leave us with a perturbed normal that is at a distance of 0.5 ,and distance of 1 at 100% strength?

Comment: Good question. What exactly _is_ the difference between increasing tilt of the normal, and adjusting the height from which it is calculated?

Comment: @RobinBetts Sorry I am not sure of the answer. Also what do you exactly mean by 'height from which it's calculated'>

Comment: I'm just saying I would like to know the answer to your Q, too. A _Bump_ node converts height information to normals, approximating `d_height / d_tangent_x`, and  `d_height / d_tangent_y`.  Often using a [Sobel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) filter.The 'Height' field scales the height input. The 'Strength' field mixes the resulting perturbed normal with straight-up Z, I think. (Could be wrong...) But I can't work out the mathematical difference between these settings.. (I have to get the pencil and paper out  :) )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding the bump node](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219059/understanding-the-bump-node)